# How to create a common service throughout the app in angular4

Tags: angular

I need a common service in all of the other services. The common service will be initiated one time only.

Lets say the common service is -

```
export Class CommonService
{
     _commonVar1= "";
     _commonVar2= "";
}
```

now the instance of common service is needed among all other services. Remember - the commonservice will be initiated one time only.

Comment: Do you know that if you put service into providers array in app module they are instantiated only once ? they are basically singleton. Looks like you really just need to declare service, register it to providers and inject it into other services. Is that not enough?

Comment: Have you tried creating the common service, then add it as a provider to your module then inject it to each service? Services are only instantiated once anyway too. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: thanks @ĽubošČurgó , adding it to providers array works.

Comment: i can make it as an answer for future references.

Comment: yeah sure. Can you please add - how to access the service in other services. This will be a great help for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put service into providers array they are instantiated only once. They are basically singleton. You register services in app module like this.

```
providers: [ArticleService, Category1Service, Category2Service],
```

In next step we will use @Injectable() decorator on top of class declaration to let angular know that class can be injected.

And then inject following service to another service using @Inject() as in example bellow.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {
    public name: string;

    constructor() {
        this.name = "Awesome article";
    };
}

@Injectable()
export class Category1Service {
    constructor(@Inject(ArticleService) public articleService: ArticleService) { }
}

@Injectable()
export class Category2Service {
    constructor(@Inject(ArticleService) public articleService: ArticleService) { }
}
```

Because our Article service is registered as singleton following is true.

```
export class FooComponent {
    constructor(
        @Inject(ArticleService) private articleService: ArticleService,
        @Inject(Category1Service) private category1Service: Category1Service,
        @Inject(Category2Service) private category2Service: Category2Service,) {

        // both will print "Awesome article" 
        console.log(category1Service.articleService.name);
        console.log(category2Service.articleService.name);

        // change name in article service
        articleService.name = "Bad article";

        // both will print "Bad article"   
        console.log(category1Service.articleService.name);
        console.log(category2Service.articleService.name);    

    }
}
```