# Same Typescript but utlizing different HTML View formats in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have a typescript form which gathers a Formbuilder data, and applies some logic to it. The customer came out with Requirement to attach a different HTML view to work with the logic. Is there optionality in Angular to keep copy the same back Typescript, but utilize a different HTML?

say this is in,

**app-mailing-address-ts.**

want to replace the html with something else,

```
  public electronicsFormChangeEvent(electronicsFormEvent) {
    this.productForm = electronicsProductEvent;
  }

  public furnitureFormChangeEvent(furnitureFormEvent) {
    this.productForm = furnitureProductEvent;
  }

  public groceryFormChangeEvent(groceryFormEvent) {
    this.productForm = groceryFormEvent;
  }


  public bookFormChangeEvent(bookFormEvent) {
    this.productForm = bookFormEvent;
  }

  public carFormChangeEvent(carFormEvent) {
    this.productForm = poBoxFormEvent;
  }


  public calculateTotalAmount() {
    if (this.productForm == 'Furniture') {
        this.TotalAmount = UnitAmount * Quantity
        ......
        .....
    }
    this.calculateTotal = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes in Angular you have different ways to share code.

There are `pipes` and `constants` and the most common:  `services`. You want to inject a shared service that contains the common code into two different components, the components will define the different HTML templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Singleton` service for common code. 
https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services
[How to create a common service throughout the app in angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530226/how-to-create-a-common-service-throughout-the-app-in-angular4)

If you need to create shared component that can be used in Template Driven Form and Reactive Form.  Here is good example 
https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-shared-components-in-angular-template-driven-and-reactive-form-ddb095cc7904